# Importing data from kaggle

Tags: python

I am new to python. I am willing to import data from Kaggle using Python.

So far I have downloaded the data from Kaggle competition.

I need to know if there is a way to download data without entering ​a competition.

Comment: as I know to download data from Kaggle you have to login. So if you want to create script for this then it has to also login to portal.

Answer (score 1):

No there isn't, you have to abide by the competition rules(Enter the competition) to download the dataset for that respective competition.